# set more action in launcher activity?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-manifest

All

I want to set two action in launcher activity in manifest as like below, So it's possible.

```
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        <action android:name="com.example.sampleapp.android.widget.buttons.ButtonWidget.ACTION_WIDGET_CONFIGURE"/>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Try it yourself and check it

Comment: it says "No Launcher activity found!
The launch will only sync the application package on the device!" But I want to set both action in activity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to define action with multiple intent-filter

```
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.example.sampleapp.android.widget.buttons.ButtonWidget.ACTION_WIDGET_CONFIGURE"/>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

check this post [Default when using multiple Actions in Intent-Filter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3188867/760489)